# Can I create an ElasticSearch index on a node/cluster, then change the cluster later?

Tags: lucene, elasticsearch

Can I create an ElasticSearch index on a cluster, let's name it "Cluster 1".

And then suppose there's another cluster "Cluster 2" I want the node to move to in the future. Is it possible to just change the cluster name in the future without impacting the data? It's ok of course if the shards move to other nodes in the cluster, but I just don't want any data loss.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, `Cluster 2` can pick up indices from a `Cluster 1` node, but you have to makes sure that:

1. The data directory on the node from `Cluster 1` is properly renamed from  `ESHOME/data/Cluster 1` to `ESHOME/data/Cluster 2` to reflect the new cluster name.
2. None of the indices that existed on the node from a `Cluster 1` already exist in the `Cluster 2`.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I believe you can change the cluster name of an es process (node) in its config and the data shards will still be there in the new cluster.